# Clear an array in Polymer?

Tags: arrays, polymer, polymer-1.0

The [polymer documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#array-mutation) says to always use the polymer array mutation functions when manipulating arrays. I do not see a function to clear an array. I see pop, push, shift, unshift and splice. For now i using this method:

```
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: "wc-example",
        properties: {
            data: { type: Array, value: function () { return [1, 2, 3]; } }
        },
        ready: function () {
            this.data = [];
        }
    });
</script>
```

This works but it doesn't seem right because i'm not using the array mutation functions. Does anyone know the correct solution?

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This perfectly ok. You are assigning a new instance to the property and this will be tracked by Polymer. Only manipulations on the same instance need to be done using the Polymer API. Note that you could use `splice` to clear an array.

```
this.splice("data", 0, this.data.length)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the splice example.